# Implications of Pessiland

Tags: np-hard, decision-problem

Consider 3COL (three colourability), Travelling Salesman, 3SAT and 2SAT. Which of these problems can be solved in polynomial time if we happen to live in world 3 (Pessiland).

My Thinking - We know that 2SAT is a P problem and so we can solve it in polynomial time even though we are in Pessiland however I am unsure on what the implications are for 3COL, travelling salesman and 3sat!

5 Worlds I refer to - http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2004/06/impagliazzos-five-worlds.html

Comment: "Pessiland" is not a widely understood term. Please include the definition of it in your question so people don't have to follow a link to find out waht you're even asking about.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, for what it's worth, the term "Pessiland" is fairly standard/well-known in the crypto-theory world (Impagliazzo's paper introducing the 5 worlds is a classic).

Answer (score 3):

The only world in which NP-complete problems (e.g. 3sat, 3colorability, traveling salesman)  are solvable in polynomial time is Algorithmica, i.e. $P=NP$.

The rest of them refer to various conjectures that might hold within $P\neq NP$, for example $NP$ problems are hard/easy on average, or one way functions do/don't exist.